# Angular2: Import returns 404, form not rendering

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Im just playing with the new Angular 2 forms implementation (or attempting to!) but can't get even a simple form to render. I dont think this is a forms problem but more of a typo somewhere on my part.

My app is as simple as:

App.ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';

import {DemoFormSku} from  './first_form';

@Component({
  selector: 'forms-demo-app',
  directives: [DemoFormSku],
  template: `
    <span>Loading complete</span>
    <div>
        <demo-form-sku></demo-form-sku>
    </div>
  `
})
export class FormsDemoApp {
}

bootstrap(FormsDemoApp, [
  //disableDeprecatedForms(),
  //provideForms()
])
.catch((err: any) => console.error(err));
```

first_form.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'demo-form-sku',
    template: `
        <div class="ui raised segment">
            <h2 class="ui header">Demo Form</div>
            <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)" class="ui form">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="skuInput">SKU</label>
                    <input type=text id="skuInput" placeholder="SKU" name="sku" ngModel>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="ui button">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    `
})
export class DemoFormSku{
    onSubmit(form:any): void{
        console.log('you submitted value: ', form);
    }
}
```

When I run this in the browser, all I see is my header and the 'Loading...' prompt. If I look in the command prompt I can see that a request for /first_form returned a 404.
If I comment out this line from app.ts
`directives: [DemoFormSku],` then
I see 'Loading complete' rather than just loading... so it looks like the import of my other directive (DemoFormSku) is the problem, but I can't figure out what it is.
In the browser console all I get in terms of error is:

> zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:8080/first_form 404 (Not Found)

Which doesn't help much.
I'm sure I've missed something simple here. Could do with a pointer as to what though!

Thanks

Comment: first_form.ts is in same folder where App.ts present

Comment: Unless angular changed their things again, I think you are also missing an import for the form. `import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FORM_PROVIDERS, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES} from "@angular/forms";` (something like this depending on what you want)

Comment: @VeerendraBorra yes, its in the same folders as app.ts

Comment: @DylanMeeus I dont think its form related as I can comment out the form from the template entirely. I dont think the first-form itself is being loaded. Even if I just put a div tag with some text in there and remove the form it doesn't render

Comment: bootstrap(FormsDemoApp, [
  //disableDeprecatedForms(),
  //provideForms()
])  uncomment it  and try

Comment: already have. I get a different error then which again I believe is unrelated. "Unexpected token <". Hence, I left it commented out until I can at last load the component with the form in.